# You need to choose options for your item while adding product to cart

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, addtocart, php-7, save

Trying to add configurable product to cart with custom qty with below code but getting You need to choose options for your item error.

```
foreach($optionQty as $key => $qty) {
            $storeId = $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface')->getStore()->getId();
            $productloaded = $this->_objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->setStoreId($storeId)->load($pid);

            if($qty > 0) {
                $params = [
                    'form_key' => $this->formKey->getFormKey(),
                    'product' => $productloaded->getId(),
                    'qty' => $qty,
                    'super_attribute' => [
                        $attributeId => $key
                    ],
                ];


                $productloaded->addCustomOption('additional_options', json_encode($additionalOptions));
                $this->cart->addProduct($productloaded, $params);

            }

        }
         $this->cart->save();
         $this->cart->getQuote()->setTotalsCollectedFlag(false)->collectTotals()->save();
```

Params array look like

```
    Array
(
    [form_key] => n6fGcdLmKgonfMRM
    [product] => 37226
    [qty] => 5
    [super_attribute] => Array
        (
            [135] => 105
        )

)
```

Can anybody help me with this

Thanks

Comment: You want to add configurable product to cart?

Comment: yes configurable product

Comment: Which have two option like color and configurable Right?

Comment: Yes am already passing it  'super_attribute' => [
                        $attributeId => $key
                    ],

Comment: You have passed only single attribute, It required two attribute value.

Comment: because in my product I have one option that is size not color

Comment: 37226 this id is simple product or configurable?

Comment: this is configurable